# 8 queens puzzle with user input c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, n-queens

I was studying the 8 queens puzzle and i wrote down my version of code that solved the problem with the first queen always put on row 0.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


const int NUMBER_OF_QUEENS = 8; // Constant: eight queens
int queens[NUMBER_OF_QUEENS];
// Check whether a queen can be placed at row i and column j
bool isValid(int row, int column)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++)
    if (queens[row - i] == column // Check column
        || queens[row - i] == column - i // Check upper left diagonal
        || queens[row - i] == column + i) // Check upper right diagonal
        return false; // There is a conflict
    return true; // No conflict
}
// Display the chessboard with eight queens
void printResult()
{
    cout << "\n---------------------------------\n";
    for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; column++)
            printf(column == queens[row] ? "| Q " : "| ");
        cout << "|\n---------------------------------\n";
    }
}
// Search to place a queen at the specified row
bool search(int row)
{
    if (row == NUMBER_OF_QUEENS) // Stopping condition
        return true; // A solution found to place 8 queens in 8 rows
    for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; column++)
    {
        queens[row] = column; // Place a queen at (row, column)
        if (isValid(row, column) && search(row + 1))
            return true; // Found, thus return true to exit for loop
    }
    // No solution for a queen placed at any column of this row
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    search(0); // Start search from row 0. Note row indices are 0 to 7
    printResult(); // Display result
    return 0;
}
```

Now i want to modify it so it will take user input so it can start from rows 0-7.
I've put something like this in the main function

```
int row, col = 0;
cout << "Enter a row number from 0-7 ";
cin >> row;
search(row);// Start search from row 0. Note row indices are 0 to 7
bool yas = isValid(row, col);
cout << yas;
printResult(); // Display result
return 0;
```

However when I run it, I keep getting a syntax error or false no matter what. Is there a better way to take user input in this or did I logically do this wrong?

Comment: Please refrain from editing your question to incorporate code that fixes your problem. It invalidates answers and makes it harder to solve your problem. Once you have the answer to your question (e.g. your code wouldn't compile) you should accept the answer that fixed your problem, feel free to upvote any answers that you find useful, and move on. If you are still having problems, after doing research if you are still stuck you should just ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you missed a semicolon in your code...

```
cout << "Enter a row number from 0-7"; // here
```

Comment: Ah. My bad. I'll edit that. My problem still stands though. I'm not getting the proper boolean value I should.

Comment: Why did you need a `search(0);` after `search(row);`. Moreover, your `isValid` method accepts two parameter i.e..a row and a column.

Comment: Ok so I've edited it again. Now I've passed row and col to isValid. However every value inputed other than 0 is returning 0 or false. How can i logically fix this?

Comment: Hey...your program is absolutely fine...the problem is with your inputs...you give a correct row and column and you will get the desired output. Here...I used `row = 2` and `column = 5` and I got true in the output. [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83cf316625ae0b26)